# Sub-Namespaces for Organization Bad Practice?

Tags: c++, namespaces, organization

Would it be considered bad practice to use sub-namespaces for purely organizational purposes?  For example:

```
namespace vehicles
{
    namespace cars
    {
        // Stuff here
    }

    namespace boats
    {
        // More stuff here
    }
}
```

I can see how this would be a problem on large projects, because it would be inconvenient to type `vehicles::cars::function` a lot.  What about small projects, though?

Comment: Depends on what Stuff and More stuff is

Comment: Also note that the only reason of observing style in small programs is to get used to it in anticipation of big programs. Style, good practices, design patterns etc. rarely matter in small programs because most of them serve for easy maintainance and easy extensibility

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why would it be less inconvenient to type `vehicles::cars::function` a lot in a small project?

Remember what purpose namespaces are supposed to serve. They are supposed to avoid name clashes, and not much else.

If you invent such a convoluted namespace structure that I'm tempted to just put a few `using namespace ...`'s at the top of every file, then it defeats the purpose of namespaces.

It also doesn't really tell me much I didn't know already. What are you going to put in your `boats` namespace that I wouldn't know from the name alone was a boat? Am I going to need the clarification that "this belongs with the boats" on anything in the namespace? Most likely not, and then there's no point in having the namespace.

In general, don't ask what *problems* there are with using *any* language feature until you've found out what the *advantages* are. Every feature needs to justify itself. So what problem would your proposed namespaces solve?

If it wouldn't solve a real, actual problem, then it is a bad idea, regardless of anything else.

I always think it's instructive to look at different language's standard libraries.

.NET uses deeply nested namespaces with long names. The full name for a simple dynamic array is `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`.

As a result, *no-one ever uses the namespace*. Everyone just puts a `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of every file that needs to use a List.

And because of this, you're in trouble the moment you encounter *another* `List` class. You'll want to do the same with that, and voila, you have two `List` classes clashing.

C++ uses a very flat namespcae structure, where namespaces also have very short names.

The equivalent class in C++ is simply `std::vector`. As a result, people generally type out the namespace prefix, and so, when I add another vector class to my project, *it works'. There are no name clashes, because I use the `std::` prefix when I want to refer to the standard library vector.

Comment: I would argue with "and not much else" part. I think the most valuable thing in namespaces is ADL and the possibility to include freestanding functions into the interface of the class

Comment: @Armen: you could have those without namespaces too. Ultimately, a namespace is to *subdivide* your code. ADL is a way to circumvent that, tying code back together.

Comment: @Armen: but I agree that ADL is an important part of what makes namespaces *work* in C++. Without that, we would likely end up putting `using namespace...` everywhere in C++ as well, negating the advantages of namespaces.

Comment: I know a company which does not get "using" and writes fully qualified type names everywhere. You can imagine the code mess.

Answer (score 7):

Well, for what it's worth, I tried using deeply-nested namespaces on a medium-sized project a couple of years back, and it was absolute hell -- I spent my entire time writing typedefs :) In Java, packages work quite nicely, because you can just import things at the top of each .java file and not have major problems. In C++, it's a pain in the butt, because it's bad practice to put using directives/declarations in header files -- as a result, you end up either (a) fully-qualifying everything in headers (bleurgh) or (b) using lots of typedefs (also bleurgh). Not cool -- my advice would be to avoid like the plague, unless you enjoy writing things like:

```
centipede::autoseg::hierarchygeneration::ragbuilders::RAGBuilder<...>
```

That's not a type, it's a sentence...

Comment: Why would you use typedefs for that? I think `using` directives would be the right tool. Of course you don't put them at the top of your header, but you can use them locally, inside functions, and they won't pollute anything. If you use something a lot in a function, put a `using abcd::efgh::MyClass;` at the top of a function. Another way is a local `namespace po = boost::program_options;` to abbreviate the namespace.

Comment: @Ela782: You can put usings inside functions (although you have to repeat them in each function), but you still end up having to fully-qualify the types of member variables if you do that. You can get round that without typedefs by wrapping your class in a dummy namespace, importing things into that namespace with a using directive and then importing your class back into the enclosing namespace, but that gets a bit hacky. Namespace abbreviations work, but arguably hinder readability a bit and help solve a problem you'd rather didn't exist in the first place (over-nested namespaces).

Comment: Okay, I also agree with your last sentence :-) What do you mean with _"you still end up having to fully-qualify the types of member variables"_?

Comment: @Ela782: I mean putting usings in a member function doesn't help you when you come to write out the type of a member variable - you still end up writing the full type in that situation.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO it's not bad practice! Also consider using aliases to get around having to type the fully qualified name every time and not injecting the whole namespace where needed...

Answer (score 2):

One of the reasons for Namespaces are for organisational purposes, how finely grained you make them is up to personal preference - I keep them fairly generic personally, for example I'd have TransferObjects. Vehicles, but not go any finely grained than that. Unless you have many many types, I don't see a point in going into that much detail. But that is up to you.

If it's a small project, then should the code base be relatively small and easily navigable, thus removing the need for such an approach?